# Update data from a Spreadsheet - Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm doing a data transfer of several spreadsheets to a single one, what I do is transfer the last data of certain columns to the master spreadsheet and also insert them in the last available row of certain columns, for now, I insert all the data but I would like to to know how I can have it examine the master spreadsheet so that if those data already exist, it does not delete them but update them. The script that I have is the following ...

```
  function  Gas10(){  
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); 
  var ssh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");


var lastRow1 = ssh1.getLastRow();
var gtRange1 = ssh1.getRange("C"+(lastRow1)+":K"+(lastRow1)).getValues();
var gtRange2= ssh1.getRange("A" + (lastRow1)).getValue();

var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var ssh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
var lastRow2 = ssh2.getLastRow() + 1;
var setRange1 = ssh2.getRange(lastRow2, 4, gtRange1.length, gtRange1[0].length).setValues(gtRange1);
var setRange2 = ssh2.getRange(lastRow2, 3).setValue(gtRange2);            
}
```

I need to know how I can do it when I insert a piece of information (I already do that), but update it if it already exists. [This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAByiML5b11KviDZ3tXNCPZHOTVJT6XlybAL4F_nxWQ/edit#gid=809223211) is the example that I created so that it can be better understood, in this example I have two sheets of which from sheet 1 I pass data to sheet 2 and what I'm looking for is that sheet 2 updates all the data that are equal to (Name, Num, Proyect). I hope that now I understand better what I'm looking for.

Comment: not sure to understand clearly the question, for the moment you get values the set the values. That's basically the only way to update them, can you share a test spreadsheet. I' love to look at it and try code

Comment: You'll need to compare values somewhere in a loop. What's your data structure look like? If you don't have an ID number (or some other identifier), you'll have to compare the new data array with each row in the master sheet checking for updated values.

Comment: @JSmith Now edit the question in which I share the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Brian You gave me a good idea, in the example that I shared if I have ID but better I want to try with a data array.

Comment: Add to your code some test that compares values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you have to do is

- get the new Line you want to add to the destination spreadsheet
- get all the required datas of the destination spreadsheet
- Check if the new Line datas have the same datas than in the destination data array

  - If so change ID value
- paste changed datas in the destination spreadsheet

based on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAByiML5b11KviDZ3tXNCPZHOTVJT6XlybAL4F_nxWQ/edit#gid=809223211) The code should look something like this

```
function  Gas10(){  
    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ssh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
    var ssh2 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
    var lastRow1 = ssh1.getLastRow();
    var lastCol1 = ssh1.getLastColumn();
    var newLine = ssh1.getRange(lastRow1, 2, 1, lastCol1 - 1 ).getValues();
    var destDatas = ssh2.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < destDatas.length; i++)
  {
      if (newLine[0][0] == destDatas[i][0]
       && newLine[0][1] == destDatas[i][1]
        && newLine[0][2] == destDatas[i][2])
      {
       destDatas[i][3] = newLine[0][3];
      }
  }
  // add newLine to destDatas
    destDatas.splice(destDatas.length, 0, newLine[0]);
  var lastColumn = ssh2.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow2 = ssh2.getLastRow() + 1;
  ssh2.getRange(1, 1,  destDatas.length, lastColumn).setValues(destDatas);
  ssh1.deleteRow(lastRow1);
}
```

Comment: Hello JSmith, I tried to adapt your pseudo-code but I do not know if I did it right, what I need is to bring the last data of sheet 1 and compare it with the data of sheet 2 to see if it was already, if it is there, overwrite it and if not that I put it, I think I'm doing the pseudo-code wrong since I'm copying the values ​​from sheet 2 and placing them on the same sheet 2 but below the table, I hope you can help me, if you can see the code you make and tell me where I'm wrong I'd appreciate it.

Comment: JSmith, Thanks again, I hope some day someone else will help your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an example I played around with:**

It looks at the slave sheet for any data.  When it finds data it puts the row and col and value into an obj which is then added to an array.  When it finishes it calls the updMaster which then looks for data in those same cells (assuming that the cells are in the same place if those cells are blank then it adds data and I also changed the background to lightblue to show me where it updated the cells.

You could run the getSlaveData() for different sheets if you wish.

```
function getSlaveData(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sA=[];
  var srg=ssh.getDataRange();
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<svA.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<svA[i].length;j++){
      //if(svA[i][j]){
      if(!ssh.getRange(i+1,j+1).isBlank()){//optional way to look for values
        var sObj={};
        sObj['row']=i + 1;
        sObj['col']=j + 1;
        sObj['value']=svA[i][j];
        sA.push(sObj);
      }
    }
  }
  updMaster(sA);
}

function updMaster(sA){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++){
    if(msh.getRange(sA[i].row,sA[i].col).isBlank()){
      msh.getRange(sA[i].row,sA[i].col).setValue(sA[i].value);
      msh.getRange(sA[i].row,sA[i].col).setBackground('lightblue');
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper for your help but JSmith's response helped me a little bit and I understood it better, thanks in the same way: D